# A with-input-from-pipe for Guile

Tags: scheme

I wrote this `with-input-from-pipe` function for Guile. I’m not that comfortable with `dynamic-wind` or `set-current-input-port`, so I’d appreciate any critiques.

```
(use-modules (ice-9 popen)
             (srfi srfi-26))

(define (with-input-from-pipe command thunk)
  (let ((old (current-input-port))
        (pipe (open-input-pipe command)))
    (dynamic-wind
      (cute set-current-input-port pipe)
      thunk
      (lambda ()
        (set-current-input-port old)
        (close-pipe pipe)))))
```